# Change Elastic Beanstalk Configuration To Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am currently running a Node JS configuration for an Elastic Beanstalk app. I want to change the environment to Docker without having to delete the environment. Does anyone know how I can do this?

There is an action to rebuild the environment, but I am not sure if that will let me change the configuration.

I don't have anything uploaded to the environment yet, so I am not worried about the files or database getting removed.

Any ideas?

**EDIT:**

My issue is that I have a DNS on another server pointing to my elastic beanstalk domain (domain.elasticbeanstalk.com). If I delete the app can I get that name back?

Comment: From what I know it's not possible, you have to create different environment :-/ List of all options for environment update http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html

Comment: @sap1ens My issue is that I have a DNS on another server pointing to my elastic beanstalk domain (domain.elasticbeanstalk.com). If I delete the app can I get that name back?

Comment: Ah, it's easy to solve! You just create another environment with URL domain2.elasticbeanstalk.com and then use Swap URL feature - it works almost instantly.

Comment: @sap1ens, thank you sir. This worked! If you want to write an answer below I will mark it as correct. Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, I'm glad it worked for you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't actually change environment type between Docker, Node.js, etc. (based on that http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/command-options.html), but you can create a new environment with different domain and use Swap CNAME feature. In this case your new environment will get the same URL (and old one can be safely deleted).

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the EB CLI. (3.2+)
Just do an `eb config` and change the solution stack name to the exact solution stack string desired.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do this without url-swapping or deleting and re-creating the environment using the aws cli.  It may be kind of a hack, but it's not too bad and it works.

First, update the environment to use the new solutionstack.  I found that I had to remove an optionsetting that was not supported in the new solutionstack, and I had to simultaneously change to the new app-version that would work on the new solutionstack:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk update-environment --solution-stack-name \
"64bit Amazon Linux 2016.03 v2.1.0 running Docker 1.9.1" \
--environment-name my-env-name \
--options-to-remove Namespace=aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python,OptionName=WSGIPath \
--version-label new-version-label
```

This command works, but results in a messed up environment, because beanstalk updates all the settings, but you've still got an underlying EC2 with the old solutionstack on it.  So rebuild the environment:

```
aws elasticbeanstalk rebuild-environment --environment-name my-env-name
```

The environment comes back up just fine!